# Is there a function that can change the appearance of google sheets based on the active user?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am making a spreadsheet to keep track of trainings for my work. All of the trainers have access to this google sheets document. I would like to make a function using apps script that could change the appearance of the spreadsheet based on the active user. Mostly, if accessed by a certain user, I want the colors of the columns to be different than the rest of the users. Another helpful thing could be bigger font.

I believe this is possible using the getActiveUser funtion, however, I do not know how to then use that to create a function where if the user is "specific person:" do this. I also dont know what information is needed for the specific person. Like if i need their user id, or how to get that. I have tried using filter views instead of apps script but have had no luck there either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look  at class range there are formatting method in this [class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Get user mthods [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session)